# Aggregation returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have been using **mongoose ODM** with **Nodejs** environment, during my development I faced such problem. I need to get a list of docs and perform some aggregation operations on these docs. In order to get specific docs I used **$match** aggregation, but it does not work,
I have tried to use without $match stage, so it worked (it returned some docs),
but I have to specify exact field and I used match, but it returns an empty array.
My pipeline below (using mongoose):

```
const comments = await Comments.aggregate([
            {
                '$match': {
                    'article_id': Types.ObjectId(id)
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind':
                    {
                        path: '$replies'
                    }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'replies.sender',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    'pipeline': [
                        {'$project': {'first_name': 1, 'last_name': 1, '_id': 0}}
                    ],
                    as: 'replies.sender'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind': {
                    path: '$replies.sender'
                }
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': '$_id',
                    'replies': {
                        '$push': '$replies'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    from: 'comments',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind': {
                    path: '$commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$addFields': {
                    'commentDetails.replies': '$replies'
                }
            },
            {
                '$replaceRoot': {
                    'newRoot': '$commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind':
                    {
                        path: '$replies'
                    }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: 'replies.receiver',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    'pipeline': [
                        {'$project': {'first_name': 1, 'last_name': 1, '_id': 0}}
                    ],
                    as: 'replies.receiver'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind': {
                    path: '$replies.receiver'
                }
            },
            {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': '$_id',
                    'replies': {
                        '$push': '$replies'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    from: 'comments',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind': {
                    path: '$commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$addFields': {
                    'commentDetails.replies': '$replies'
                }
            },
            {
                '$replaceRoot': {
                    'newRoot': '$commentDetails'
                }
            },
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': 'users',
                    'localField': 'user_id',
                    'foreignField': '_id',
                    'pipeline': [
                        {'$project': {'first_name': 1, 'last_name': 1, '_id': 0}}
                    ],
                    'as': 'user'
                }
            },
            {
                '$unwind': '$user'
            },
        ]).sort({'date_time': 'descending'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just added `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` to `$unwind`